# Stalk of coherent sheaf vanishing

Tags: algebraic-geometry

is the following true:
if I have a coherent sheaf $F$ on a noetherian scheme $X$ with a point $x$ and the stalk $F_x$ is zero, then there is a neighborhood $U$ of $x$, such that the restriction of $F$ to $U$ is zero?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. For the locality of the problem, you can assume that $X$ is affine: $X = \mathrm{Spec} A$ and $F = \tilde{M}$, where $A$ is a noetherian ring and $M$ is a finite $A$-module. Let $P$ a prime such that $M_P = 0$. Let $\{ x_1, \dots, x_n \}$ a set of generators of $M$ as an $A$-module. Then exist $s_i \in A \setminus P$ such that $s_i x_i = 0$. Pick $s = s_1 \cdots s_n$, then $F \vert_{D(s)} = 0$.

Comment: You're welcome! With a similar proof, you may try to solve Exercise II.5.8(a) of Hartshorne.

Comment: Do we really need Noetherianity here? It seems that all is used is that the module is finitely generated.

Comment: @AreaMan,  you are absolutely right: we don't need Noetherianity hypothesis. The result holds for any finitely generated sheaf of $\mathcal O_X$- Modules over any scheme (or even over any locally ringed space).